# linkedin oauth2 ApI can't callback to native Ios Apps

Tags: ios

I have already used IOS LinkedIn API with this below object method for getting the callback URL in my native iOS App ..

```
 - (LIALinkedInHttpClient *)client 
 {
    LIALinkedInApplication *application = [LIALinkedInApplication applicationWithRedirectURL:@"https://www.google.com/auth/linkedin/callback"
                                                                             clientId:@"put your ID hear"
                                                                             clientSecret:@"put yor secret Key hear"
                                                                             state:@"DCEEFWF45453sdffef424"
                                                                             grantedAccess:@[@"r_basicprofile",@"w_share",@"r_emailaddress"]];

   return [LIALinkedInHttpClient clientForApplication:application presentingViewController:nil];

 }
```

Comment: how can i solve this issue ..please suggest some demo application which uses a ios 8 and linked in Oauth2 API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this library, It works for me :

https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI

Add your **Redirect URL**, **Client ID** and **Client Secret** exactly as listed in your LinkedIn developer account in the below code :

```
LIALinkedInApplication *application = [LIALinkedInApplication applicationWithRedirectURL:REDIRECT_URL  clientId:LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID clientSecret:LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET state:@"DCEEFWF45453sdffef424" grantedAccess:@[@"r_basicprofile"]];
```